# ASP.net MVC content place holder obliterating existing tag content

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a content placeholder on my master page;

```
<title>
    CompanyName - <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="TitleContent" runat="server" />
</title>
```

Which I thought would let me add the following to any views;

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    Home Page
</asp:Content>
```

and would subsequently render the title as;

```
<title>CompanyName - Home Page</title>
```

but what I'm getting is;

```
<title>Home Page</title>
```

I've checked and double checked the code and I can't see why I would be getting the content overwritten, unless there's something extremely fundamental I've missed from the MVC2 framework!

Comment: Why are you using a web forms server control in an MVC project??

Comment: @Shark, because that's how master pages work when you use the WebForms view engine in ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: @shark Darin is correct - not using Razor here unfortunately. Rest assured these are the only webforms server controls I'm using in the views!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `runat="server"` from your `<head>` (sounds funny :-)):

So in your master page replace:

```
<head runat="server">
```

with:

```
<head>
```

Comment: Thanks, worked a treat. Do you know what the implications of doing this are? I had no intention of accessing the head element from the server anyway but am a bit worried about losing some under-the-hood functionality by doing this.

Comment: @MikeyHogarth, don't worry, you will loose functionality that's not intended to be used in ASP.NET MVC anyway, so it's a good thing to remove it.